# Email verifiy based on mailgun api reading the json response

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to make an email validator based on Mailgun API but I'm stuck at the reading the json response.

this is my code:

```
  foreach (string str in this.ema.Items)
  {
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/address/validate?api_key=" + this.chei.Text + "&address=" + str);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    if (new StreamReader(httpWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd().Contains(" \"mailbox_verification\": true"))
      this.m_oWorker.ReportProgress(percentProgress, (object) str);
    else
      this.m_oWorker.ReportProgress(0, (object) str);
    ++percentProgress;
  }
  this.m_oWorker.ReportProgress(1);
}
```

this is the response from json:

```
{"address": "foo@mailgun.net",
"did_you_mean": null,
"is_disposable_address": false,
"is_role_address": true,
"is_valid": true,
"mailbox_verification": "true",
"parts": {
    "display_name": null,
    "domain": "mailgun.net",
    "local_part": "foo"
}
```

mind the quotation marks around "mailbox_verification": "true", I think there is my mistake but I don't know of to solve it.

Comment: If their API returns `"true"`, especially when other boolean values return correctly, that seems like a bug. Would suggest you contact them.

Answer (score 1):

One way in which this could be easily overcome would be to create a model of the API response and use `Newtonsoft.Json` to deserialise the JSON string into your model. The `mailbox_verification` will be parsed into the type presented in the given model (`bool` in this instance) which will give you the explicit type you're after.

**Models:**

```
public class MailGunResponse
{
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string did_you_mean { get; set; }
        public bool is_disposable_address { get; set; }
        public bool is_role_address { get; set; }
        public bool is_valid { get; set; }
        public bool mailbox_verification { get; set; } //Make sure it is bool!
        public Parts parts { get; set; }
}


public class Parts
{
        public string display_name { get; set; }
        public string domain { get; set; }
        public string local_part { get; set; }
 }
```

**Deserialise:**

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("test.json"); //Change to you JSON string source.
var jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MailGunResponse>(json);
```